# Magento backend_model not triggering on load and save

Tags: php, magento, phpunit

This is a wierd situation because magento is loading my backend model, its just not calling it when I load and save it. I know this because 1. I see it in my database, 2. when I rename my backend model, my test case fails. Here is my code

It saves my values just fine and completely ignores my afterload and beforesave methods.

## TEST CASE

```
<?php

class Super_Base_Test_Controller_Test extends  EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case_Controller {

    const DEFAULTSTORE = 1;

    public function setUpMocks() {
        $this->setCurrentStore(1);
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')
            ->load(1);
        $customer->setCoinBalance(20)
            ->save();
    }


    public function setUp() {
        $this->setUpMocks();
        $data = array(
            'customer_id'=>1,
            'message'=>'this is a test message',
            'income'=>20,
            'created_at'=>'9/11/84',
            'updated_at'=>'9/11/84',
            'current'=>1
        );
        $this->getRequest()->setParams($data);
    }

    protected function getTearDownOperation() {
        return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Factory::TRUNCATE();
    }

}
```

## backend model

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: numerical25
 * Date: 3/8/14
 * Time: 6:22 PM
 */


class Super_Coin_Model_Customer_Attribute_Coinbalance extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract {
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        if (!is_array($this->getValue())) {
            $value = $this->getValue();
            $this->setValue(empty($value) ? false : unserialize($value));
        }
    }

    protected function _beforeSave() {
        if (is_array($this->getValue())) {
            $this->setValue(serialize($this->getValue()));
        }
    }

    public function setCoinAmount($amount) {
        $this->setValue($amount);
    }
}
```

## installation file

```
$eavsetup->addAttribute('customer', 'coin_balance', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'decimal',
    'label'         => 'Customer Coin Balance',
    'backend' => 'coin/customer_attribute_coinbalance',
    'global'       => 1,
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1, ));
```

When I set break points, the system completly ignores my methods.

Answer (score 0):

Look at abstract class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract. It contains the following public methods: beforeSave() and afterLoad().

There are no _afterLoad() and _beforeSave() methods in that class